# Matlab error while finding log

Tags: matlab, logarithm

I am trying to find `log` of `base 10` of each pixel of an image in matlab using following code

```
m1 = imread('owl','pgm');
for x = 1:size(m1,1)
    for y = 1:size(m1,2)
        m1(x,y) = log10(m1(x,y));  
    end
end
```

here m1 is a 2-D array of order 221 X 201.
but I am facing this error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'log2' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in ==> log10 at 20
y = log2(x);

Error in ==> q2 at 38
        m1(x,y) = log10(m1(x,y));
```

but when I debug log function using following code

```
fprintf('log of 190 is %d', log10(190));
```

it gives me right output I dont know what happened when I use the same code in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is, you've tried to apply the `log10` function to  a value of type `uint8` and the function is not defined for that type of number. What you haven't realised is that `imread`, when an image file meets certain criteria (read the documentation for what those criteria are) will capture the pixel data into an array of `uint8`s, not real numbers.

If you want to take the logarithm of a `uint8` you'll either have to define a logarithm function of your own which takes such inputs, or, more straightforward, cast the `uint8` to a type which `log10` is happy with.  For example, you could write:

```
log10(double(m1(x,y)))
```

And by now you'll have realised why your diagnostic test didn't tell you anything useful, when you execute the command `log10(190)` Matlab, by default, decides that `190` is of type `double` and computes the logarithm without complaint.  `log10(uint8(190))` tells a different story.